# Regarding perl unpack

Tags: perl

I am planning to use unpack in the file.  First i tested with a string.  When i have a embedded space in a string the below script is showing it as null.  When i tested with a  file space is getting read properly.  Not sure why it's changing it to null when i do with string.  Can i use unpack while reading a fixed length file?  Do i need to consider trailing space or anything else?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $str="hek kaaa";
print "<$str>\n";
foreach(unpack("(A1)*", $str)) {
    print sprintf("%x", ord), " ";
}

Output:
<hek kaaa>
68 65 6b 0 6b 61 61 61
```

Thanks a lot for the response. Pasted my query below

When the perl program reads from a text file and unpacks using the format "A" is working properly. First line i have a embedded space in the first field between A and D.  LABEL Variable gets printed as "A D3".   But when i had a variable $str="A D3" and   unpacked  the below way it's having a null after A.  How is it working differently when reading from  a file and variable?

```
foreach(unpack("(A1)*", $str)) {
    print sprintf("%x", ord), " ";
}
```

it displays as the hex output as 
 
41 0 44 33

```
cat test.txt
A D37845566974923342XYZ24023984
QRW49327408234028434ERD24448009

 my $file = 'test.txt';

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file'\n";
while (my $line = <$data>) {
    print $line;
    chomp $line;
    my ($label, $source, $dest, $type, $value) = unpack ("A4 A8 A8 A4 A8", $line);
    print "LABEL: $label SOURCE: $source DEST: $dest TYPE: $type VALUE: $value\n";
    print "length of a string:" . length($line) . "\n";
    foreach(unpack("(a1)*", $label)) {
       print sprintf("%x", ord), " ";
    }
    print "\n";

}
```

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? It looks like you're going about it in a really awkward way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This little nugget in the [`pack/unpack`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#pack) documentation is easy to miss:

> The "a", "A", and "Z" types gobble just one value, but
>   pack it as a string of length count, padding with nulls
>   or spaces as necessary.  **When unpacking, "A" strips
>   trailing whitespace and nulls**, "Z" strips everything
>   after the first null, and "a" returns data verbatim.

As a workaround, you can use a `a` or `Z` in the template instead of `A`:

```
$ perl -e 'print ord unpack("A", " ")'
0

$ perl -e 'print ord unpack("a", " ")'
32

$ perl -e 'print ord unpack("Z", " ")'
32
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  When i have a text file

Comment: This was very helpful... thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

`pack 'A'` pads with spaces, so `unpack 'A'` removes trailing spaces. (Actually, whitespace and NULs.)

```
>perl -E"say(($ARGV[0] eq unpack('A20', pack('A20', $ARGV[0]))) ? 1 : 0)" abc
1
```

You want "`a`".

```
unpack("(a1)*", $str)
```

That said, the "1" is superfluous.

```
unpack("(a)*", $str)
```

Finally, `split` is more commonly used for this.

```
split(//, $str)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  I had edited my question.  could you pls respond

Comment: What makes you think it's not a NUL in the file? `for ("A\x{20}D3", "A\x{00}D3") {
   print "$_: ";
   print sprintf("%02x ", $_) for unpack("C*", $_);
   print "\n";
}`